# counting the blank lines in a C program

Tags: c, lines, counting

I have to count the blank spaces in a program's code/file's text/console text. This is what I've tried so far:

```
void number_of_lines(int *brr, FILE *file)
{
    char string[60];
    int br = 0;
    //FILE *fileptr=fopen("test.txt","r");
    while (fgets(string, 60, file) != NULL)
    {
        if (string[0] == '\n')
        {
            br++;
        }
    }
    *brr = br;
}
```

The code should search for the blank lines by searching for the symbol for new line "\n" and it adds 1 to "brr" counter.

However when I delete all the words in a line, this line goes blank, but the function doesn't count it, because I haven't pressed enter(the new line "\n"), so it doesn't count it as a blank line.

So how would I count it now? Should I include if it finds the backspace symbol to add 1 to the counter or what?

(The name of the file and so on are written in another function, so I need to know only how to count the blank lines in a code,or the "if" criteria, if you have other suggestions, tell me )

Thank you :)

Comment: Side suggestion: define your function as int (instead of void) and return directly br instead of passing the pointer brr to get the modified value. Then you call your func as: brr =  number_of_lines(file).

Comment: i will add more thing to be returned in this function, its in progress ,  so i will use pointers anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `if (string[0] == '\0')` or `strcmp(string, "") == 0`.
If you don't press enter and the line is empty then the value of the string will be '\0' which indicates the end of a string.

Comment: but the "\0" is the symbol of what

Comment: Better, but why string will have '\0' ? (hint: see man fgets)

Comment: every string has the '\0' at the end of it

Comment: @skyline21 there are no string type in C! There are situations in which the terminating char is added as when you define a char array as a string literals. Pay attention on this fact, it may leads to several errors when you use dynamical memory allocation. See man fgets to understand why your string has the terminating character '\0'.

Comment: @skyline21 and array of char are not always null-terminating, unless you explicitly take care of it.

Comment: thanks for the information, im a beginner and its a bit difficult :)